# Delete record 24 hours after insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there a way to automatically delete a row 24 hours after its creation in Transact-SQL?

I'm making a site (learning experience) where the user needs to click a validation link sent by e-mail once they register. I want the users to validate themselves within 24 hours.

I suppose what I'd need is a trigger, but I'm really not sure on the syntax, nor if it is even possible.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm not sure of your schema but I would do it a different way. I would have a date/time against the database record that corresponds to the validation link. When they click the link, verify that the date and time of the database record is within 24 hours of the current time. If so, allow it, otherwise reject it.

Comment: +1. For solving the actual problem, not the percieved solution to the problem.

Comment: note: marking the row as invalid allows you to tell people 'this link has expired' (if it has expired) or 'this link is invalid' (if it doesn't exist). I assume you're using some kind of unique key such as a GUID to ensure people can't guess the reset token

Comment: Wouldn't even need to mark the row as invalid. You can determine validity by date/time.

Comment: In some similar applications I've coded the validation check to first delete any rows that are older than the allowed period, then check for the validation link value.  The SP that inserts rows can also do a delete of old rows so that the table growth is controlled.

Comment: +1 That's exactly the logic we have implemented in our databases.

Answer (score 2):

Q: Is there a way to automatically delete a row 24 hours after its creation in Transact-SQL?

A: Sure.  Write a "sqlcmd" script, wrap it in a .bat file, and invoke it from Windows Scheduled Tasks:

- http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/schedule-a-task

Alternatively, depending on your version, you could schedule the same SQL script from SQL Server Agent:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189237.aspx

Putting a different spin on things:

- When the user clicks your link, you can check if the current time (with respect to MSSQL) is >> 24 hours.  If so, you'll reply with a "Too late" message (rather than validating the entry).

In any case - you absolutely, completely, totally, do *NOT* want to use a trigger!

Comment: Why wouldn't I want to use triggers? Are they so evil that they should be cast away in a corner to be forgotten?

Comment: No.  But they're so evil as a solution to that  this particular problem you should drop a house on the idea (like Dorothy did to the Wicked Witch of the East in "The Wizard of Oz") ;)  Triggers are great for some problems ... and ridiculous for this one. The *correct* solution is to act when the user clicks the link (as I suggested in my post).  IMHO...