# C# change record in SQL database after 24 hours

Tags: c#, sql

how can i change record (like from "true" to "False") in specific row of SQL database after exactly 24 hours?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14007572/delete-record-24-hours-after-insert

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show your effort first.. Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: There is no such thing as a **SQL database**; SQL is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by many database systems, but it's **NOT** a database product... stuff like this is very often vendor-specific - so we really need to know **what database system** (and which version) you're using....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would depend on the type of application you are developing and assumes that this application is constantly running. For example if this is a web application (ASP.NET) this is definitely a very bad idea as you cannot rely on the fact whether your application will still be running at the specified time in the future or it could be stopped by IIS.

In desktop applications you could [`start a timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) and perform the db update in the callback. Another possibility is to use the [`RegisterWaitForSingleObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.registerwaitforsingleobject.aspx) method:

```
ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(
    new AutoResetEvent(false),
    (state, timedOut) =>
    {
        // this callback will execute 24 hours later
        // here you could perform your database update
    },
    null,
    TimeSpan.FromHours(24),
    true
);
```

Comment: this supposed to be part of ASP.NET site and i want to modify some record a specific row of the database from "open" to "close" exactly 24 hours from this row insertion.what is the best way to do it from the above?

Answer (score 1):

There are different options depending on what your needs are. Here are some to hep you choose:

1. SQL Server Agent (not included in Express Edition)
2. Use task scheduler and batch files.
3. Quartz .NET (http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/)
4. PowerShell

For #2, you can find info here:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlgetstarted/thread/7e00c796-5854-4a2c-91d3-7b325420fd14/

and an interesting tool to generate SQL batch files here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12203/Generating-osql-Batch-Scripts

Note, if you must do it from within your app, go with #3 or with Darin's suggestion

Comment: this supposed to be part of ASP.NET site and i want to modify some record a specific row of the database from "open" to "close" exactly 24 hours from this row insertion.what is the best way to do it from the above?

Comment: @walter Use Quartz.NET and I would recommend putting it into a windows service if possible. But if it must be done from the ASP.NET application, then look into keeping your site alive. One way is to modify IIS to do this. See here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772183%28v=ws.10%29.aspx.

Comment: @walter Actually, thinking about it again, I might opt for the SQL Server Agent job if you can. You can schedule a job to check the table every hour or every day (or whenever you want) and for each row, look at when the it was inserted. If it equals `Now - 24 hours` then set it to `close`

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do this. It would be better to have the boolean timelimited, and then check for expiration in your app.